# How to save sub-document/sub-collection with C# MongoDb.Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using [MongoDb.Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/) in C# to save information to my backend.

I've created a simple Repository to store a generic object:

```
public abstract class MongoRepository<TDocument> : IRepository<TDocument>
    where TDocument : Entity
{
    #region Private Fields
    private readonly IMongoCollection<TDocument> _collection;
    #endregion

    #region Protected Properties
    protected abstract String CollectionName { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public MongoRepository(IMongoDbSettings settings)
    {
        IMongoDatabase? database = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString).GetDatabase("default");
        _collection = database.GetCollection<TDocument>(CollectionName);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public IQueryable<TDocument> AsQueryable()
    {
        return _collection.AsQueryable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TDocument> FilterBy(
        Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
    {
        return _collection.Find(filterExpression).ToEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TProjected> FilterBy<TProjected>(
        Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression,
        Expression<Func<TDocument, TProjected>> projectionExpression)
    {
        return _collection.Find(filterExpression).Project(projectionExpression).ToEnumerable();
    }

    public async Task<TDocument> FindOne(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
    {
        return await _collection.Find(filterExpression).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TDocument>> Get()
    {
        IAsyncCursor<TDocument>? asyncCursor = await _collection.FindAsync(_ => true);
        return await asyncCursor.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<TDocument> Get(Guid id)
    {
        FilterDefinition<TDocument>? filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id, id);
        return await _collection.Find(filter).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task Create(TDocument document)
    {
        await _collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
    }

    public async Task CreateMany(ICollection<TDocument> documents)
    {
        await _collection.InsertManyAsync(documents);
    }

    public async Task Update(TDocument document)
    {
        FilterDefinition<TDocument>? filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id, document.Id);
        await _collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(filter, document);
    }

    public async Task Delete(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression)
    {
        await _collection.DeleteManyAsync(filterExpression);
    }

    public async Task Delete(Guid id)
    {
        FilterDefinition<TDocument>? filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id, id);
        await _collection.FindOneAndDeleteAsync(filter);
    }

    public async Task Delete(TDocument element)
    {
        await Delete(element.Id);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Up until now it was working fine, but I first encounter the case of saving an object that has sub-objects and collections:

```
public class Dashboard : Entity//Entity has just a public Guid Id {get;set;}
{
    public Guid OrganizationLevelId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsShared { get; set; }
    public Guid? OwnerId { get; set; }
    public List<Widget> Widgets { get; } = new();
}
```

And now, when I'm trying to save a document that has a collection, the array of widgets isn't saved:

```
await _dashboardsRepository.Create(new Dashboard()
   {
      Name = "Default Dashboard",
      IsShared = true,
      Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
      OrganizationLevelId = rootLevel.Id,
      Widgets =
      {
         new Widget() {Columns = 2, Rows = 1, Y = 0, X = 0, Title = "Component 1"},
         new Widget() {Columns = 1, Rows = 1, Y = 1, X = 0, Title = "Comp 2"},
         new Widget() {Columns = 1, Rows = 1, Y = 1, X = 1, Title = "Comp 3"},
         new Widget() {Columns = 2, Rows = 2, Y = 0, X = 1, Title = "Max 2x2", MaxItemsColumns = 2, MaxItemsRows = 2},
         new Widget() {Columns = 2, Rows = 3, Y = 0, X = 4, Title = "Min 2x2", MinItemColumns = 2, MinItemsRows = 2},
         new Widget() {Columns = 4, Rows = 2, Y = 2, X = 0, Title = "Component 6"},
         new Widget() {Columns = 2, Rows = 2, Y = 3, X = 4, Title = "Component 7"}
      }
}
)
```

I'm trying to keep some kind of separation of concern, so my business objects doesn't reference MongoDb.

I guess there is something to indicate that I want the child properties to be persisted but I can't find how, any idea?

Comment: Widgets = new List<Widget> { add widgets here }

Comment: @jdweng Hi! Thanks for the answer. I'm probably dumm, but how is this different that what I'm doing when I call the repository?

Comment: It has to do with overload of methods.  You are calling with Create(TDocument document).  The class is not a TDocument so the Create method is never called.

Comment: @jdweng Yes it is. My `DashBoardRepository` is a `MongoRepository<Dashboard>`

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue. In fact there was no additional "serialization" required, but I did 2 changes:

My "Widgets" property was a

`public List<Widget> Widgets{get;} = new List<Widget>()`

After I transformed it to

`public List<Widget> Widgets{get;set;}`(and initialize the collection when creating a dashboard)

it works.

I'm not sure if it's because of the missing setter or the default initialization of the collection, but it works now.